# Hide user profile field based on its own value

Tags: users

Situation:

- I added a boolean field named `Fee waived` to the user account.
- On the edit form, this field is represented as a single checkbox.
- Users cannot edit the value; only admins can see and edit it (I'm using `field_permissions`).
- When the checkbox is selected, `Fee waived: Yes` appears in the user profile. I want this.
- When the checkbox is NOT selected, `Fee waived: No` appears in the user profile. I don't want this. I don't want anything to show (because I don't want users wondering how to get their fee waived).

By default, when a user account field is empty, nothing is displayed for it in the user profile. However, a non-checked checkbox is not empty; it has a value of 0 (or whatever has been defined for it). This is why I get `Fee waived: No` in the user profile.

Question:

Is there a simple way to keep the field from being displayed in the user profile when it is not selected?

Attempted solutions:

- If the `conditional_fields` module would allow a field to be dependent upon itself, that would work beautifully to solve the problem. But it does not. I tried disabling the 'same field' check in the module's code. This works, in that the field is hidden exactly as I want it to be, but when the `dependent` and `dependee` fields are the same: (1) the dependency configuration form ceases to hide irrelevant fields due to a Javascript error and (2) a PHP error is thrown when the dependency is saved. These can be ignored and the dependency still works, but it makes the solution ugly.
- I tried other modules that allow value-based field control (`field conditional state` and `field formatter settings`), but none seem to allow a field to depend upon itself.
- I placed a span tag with the class `conceal` in the `Off value` for the boolean field and then injected the following Javascript into the user profile page:

  `jQuery("span.conceal").closest("div.field").css("display", "none");`

  This works, but when the profile is displayed, the user sees a "hiccup" as the to-be-hidden field is briefly shown and then hidden.

Comment: I thought the field permissions module had a check for viewing a field. If you take away the user's role from viewing, what happens?

Comment: Thanks @Niall Murphy. Apparently, my question wasn't clear. I have rewritten it to make it better. I want the field to appear on the user profile page when the checkbox is selected and to not appear when it is not selected. field_permissions makes a field either always there or never there, but doesn't allow conditions based on values, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the most straightforward solution I could find was to:

- create a duplicate user profile field named `Fee waived dup`.
- use `field_permissions` to always hide this field from all users.
- create a rule to set `Fee waived dup` equal to `Fee waived` when the user account is saved.
- use the `conditional_fields` module to display `Fee waived` only when `Fee waived dup` is true.

If there were multiple fields to be hidden based on their own values, this might not be such a good solution. I have only one such field, so it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is in a twig template that renders the profile. Something like:

```
{% if user.field_fee_waived is not empty and user.field_fee_waived.value == 1 %}
  {{ content.field_fee_waived }}
{% endif %}
```

Basically, twig looks at the user object to see if the field is present, and that its value is 1/true. If not, it won't render the field. This same approach can work on `node` or `paragraphs` or any entity that gets passed along to a template. `content.field_fee_waived` is the render array that renders that specific field to your configuration you set under `Manage Display`.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. Your answer gave me reason to read up on twig templates. Very interesting. In the end, creating a separate template to solve this problem was more than I cared to do, but now I have a solution for more complex situations.